# React router v6 set redirect default children in nest router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
const routes = [{
    path: '/',
    element: <Layout/>,
    children: [
        {
            path: '/home',
            element: <Home/>,
        }
    ]
}]
```

I hava two components, `Home` and `Layout`.
I would like to redirect my url for e.g to '/home' when I only write `/`, but here is a problem:`Layout` can't bind element.

```
{
    path: '/',
    element:  <Navigate to="/home"/>
}
```

or use index router, but I can't set path = '/home', `Layout` and `Home` use same url `/`, I don't want this.

I use React router version `"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"`, So how can I set default router?